# How to find a href control with javascript popup from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this code in gridview in .aspx, and actually having 31 of these for 31 days:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" 28" SortExpression="Data28"
<ItemTemplate>
<a id="data28" href="javascript:openPopup('/subsidy/updatehour1.aspx?Data=<%# Eval("Data28") %>&TraineeID=<%#Eval("TraineeID")%>&RecordID=<%# Eval("RecordID")%>')">
<%# Eval("Data28")%>
</a>
</ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If I add `runat="server"`, then there is an error when I run the page.

In the code behind, I need to use folowing code to hide specific href in the gridview:

```
    private void setMonthEndTextBox()
    {
        int lastDay = (int)ViewState["LastDay"];
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 29; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                ((HtmlAnchor)row.Cells[i + 4].FindControl("Data" +   i.ToString())).Visible = (i <= lastDay);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to do it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HtmlAnchor is the wrong method in your code

```
private void setMonthEndTextBox()
    {
        int lastDay = (int)ViewState["LastDay"];
        foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 29; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                ((HtmlAnchor)row.Cells[i + 4].FindControl("Data" +   i.ToString())).Visible = (i <= lastDay);
            }
        }
    }
```